# Program crashing after randomization of a float

Tags: c, random, double

The program seems to crash on line 54 when calculating circles[3][6]. What could be causing this? I entered a bunch of print statements to find out some information and everything seems to be going great until exactly [3][6], which doesn't seem to be anything special for it to crash on.

```
int main() {

double a, b, circleXMax, circleYMax, circleRMax;
double rand_float(double a, double b);
int i, j;
int circleInfo = 3;
int circleNum = 50;
int PI = 3.14;
double circleArea;
double circleAreaMax = 0;
double circles[circleInfo][circleNum];

printf("Opened \n");

for(i = 1; i <= circleNum; i++) {
    printf("Start of i = %d \n", i);
    for(j = 1; j <= circleInfo; j++) {
        printf("Start of j = %d \n", j);
        if(j == 1 || j == 2) {
            printf("Start of randomization of j (%d) \n", j);
            circles[j][i] = rand_float(100.00, 900.00);
            printf("circles[%d][%d] = %f \n", j, i, circles[j][i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("Start of randomization of j (%d) \n", j);
            circles[j][i] = rand_float(0.00, 100.00);
            printf("circles[%d][%d] = %f \n", j, i, circles[j][i]);
        }
    }
    printf("Start of calculation of circleArea \n");
    circleArea = PI * circles[3][i] * circles[3][i];
    printf("Completed calculation of circleArea = %f \n", circleArea);
    if(circleArea >= circleAreaMax) {
        printf("circle was larger then maximum current \n");
        circleAreaMax = circleArea;
        circleXMax = circles[1][i];
        circleYMax = circles[2][i];
        circleRMax = circles[3][i];
    } else {
        printf("circle was NOT larger then maximum current \n");
    }
}

printf("Circle with largest area (%f) has\n", circleAreaMax);
printf("center (%f, %f) and radius %f", circleXMax, circleYMax, circleRMax);

   }

   double rand_float(double a, double b) {
      printf("doing a randomization via rand_float \n");
      return (((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*(b-a))+a;
   }
```

It crashes after saying:

> "Start of j = 3"
>
> "Start of randomization of j (3)"
>
> "doing a randomization via rand_float"

Comment: You do remember that array indexes start from `0` and go to the size minus one?

Comment: @Evan Did you actually understand the previous comment? I don;t think so.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I notice is with the loop boundary. Both the cases

```
 for(i = 1; i <= circleNum; i++)
```

and

```
for(j = 1; j <= circleInfo; j++)
```

cause [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

C arrays have 0-based indexing, so for an array defined like `<type> arr[m][n]`, the highest possible valid indexing would be `arr[m-1][n-1]`.

That said, some other comments:

- You have function declaration inside `main()`, they need to be in the file scope to be visible to the whole translation unit. Otherwise only `main()` and functions defined after them will have the declaration available to them.
- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, for a hosted environment to conform to the standard (*unless you're using a specialized environment which explicitly defines the former to be a valid signature*).

Comment: I figured it could store at m and n, but I was wrong, thanks!

Comment: @StoryTeller I see, the later was not my intention, indeed. Any suggestions on how to improve the wordings to clear out any confusions? Thanks in advance. :)